# В нормальном ли режиме работает оперативная память?

Tags: windows, железо, ram

Добрый день ребят. Установил 4 модуля памяти по 4гб. Но не пойму что с частотой. В AIDA показывает следующее. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это нормальный двухканальный режим работы, или что-то не так с частотами и настройками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Память работает на своей штатной частоте 666МГц, чтобы она работала на 800МГц скорее всего надо настраивать в BIOS'е (если такую частоту памяти поддерживает материнская плата), там же в BIOS'е можно посмотреть режим работы, одноканальный или нет.